# Vue with Typescript: Issue encountered when translating Vue application from JavaScript to TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, loader

I'm trying to translate a Vue project from JavaScript to TypeScript without using the class-style syntax.

Here are the steps I followed:

- I executed: `vue add typescript`
- I translated all my `.vue` files in:

  - Specifying that TypeScript is the used-language: `<script lang="ts">`
  - `export default {` -> `export default Vue extend({`
  - Created a `types.d.ts` with my custom types and imported it in the `types` option of `tsconfig.json`.
  - Specified the types in the code when possible.

However, when I'm running the application, I get this error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (23:16)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   data() {
|     return {
>       todos: [] as Todo[]
|     };
|   },
```

It seems that the loaders the project is using do not recognize the TypeScript syntax. Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found the issue. I was running the app using `vue serve` instead of `npm run serve`. For whatever reason, it solved it.